# Generating heat/density map with PostGIS from point data

Tags: database, postgresql, gis, postgis, heatmap

I have a huge table (gps_points) with a geometry column storing 2D-points. What I'm trying to accomplish is to run a query that output something like

```
 id | freq
-------------
  1 | 365
  2 | 1092
  3 | 97
...
```

where "id" is a unique identifier of a small rectangle inside my total bounding box and "freq" is the number of points that fall inside that particular rectangle.

So I have defined a PostGIS table as:

```
create table sub_rects (
id int,
geom geometry)
```

I then run a script externally, where I generate 1000x1000 such rectangles and create polygons of them, so I get a million lines like this:

```
insert into sub_rects values(1,ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((1.1 1.2, 1.1 1.4, 1.5 1.4, 1.5 1.2, 1.1 1.2))'));
```

except of course every polygon gets itself a new set of co-ordinates to match its actual place in the 1000x1000 grid over the bounding box co-ordinates of my gps data, and the ID gets updated for each tuple.

Then I generate a spatial index and a primary key index on this table.

Finally I can run this table and my original data table (gps_points) with

```
select id, count(*) from sub_rects r join gps_points g on r.geom && g.geom group by id;
```

which gives me my sought output. The problem is that it takes forever to load all the little polygons and that every time I want to generate a map with a different number of rectangles or running over a data set with different underlying co-ordinates, I have to drop sub_rects and generate and load it anew.

Is there a better way of doing this? I don't need graphic output. I just need to  generate the data. Not having to generate the support table (sub_rects) externally would be very nice, and I suspect there are way less computationally expensive methods of accomplishing the same thing. I would much prefer not to have to install any additional software.

ETA: As per request in comments, here is the query plan (on my home machine, so smaller data sets and other table names, but the same plan):

```
gisdb=# explain analyse select g.id id, count(*) from gridrect g join broadcast b on g.geom && b.wkb_geometry group by g.id;

    QUERY PLAN
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 GroupAggregate  (cost=0.57..177993.58 rows=10101 width=12) (actual time=14.740..3528.600 rows=1962 loops=1)
   Group Key: g.id
   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.57..144786.36 rows=6621242 width=4) (actual time=13.948..3050.741 rows=1366376 loops=1)
         ->  Index Scan using gridrect_id_idx on gridrect g  (cost=0.29..485.30 rows=10201 width=124) (actual time=0.079..6.582 rows=10201 loops=1)
         ->  Index Scan using broadcast_wkb_geometry_geom_idx on broadcast b  (cost=0.29..12.78 rows=137 width=32) (actual time=0.011..0.217 rows=134 loops=10201)
               Index Cond: (g.geom && wkb_geometry)
 Planning time: 0.591 ms
 Execution time: 3529.320 ms
(8 rows)
```

ETA 2:

As per suggestions in the answers I modified the code suggested there to this:

```
(SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY geom) id, geom
 FROM (SELECT st_geomfromtext(
                  concat('Polygon((', x || ' ' || y, ',', x + xstep || ' ' || y, ',', x + xstep || ' ' || y + ystep,
                         ',', x || ' ' || y + ystep, ',', x || ' ' || y, '))')) geom
       FROM (SELECT x, y
             FROM (SELECT generate_series(xmin, xmin + xdelta, xstep) x) x,
                  (SELECT generate_series(ymin, ymin + ydelta, ystep) y) y) foo) bar);
```

where xmin, ymin, xdelta, ydelta, xstep and ystep are all calculated by an external script, but might just as well be calculated as a part of a Postgres function if you wrapped the above in a function call. Generating a temporary table from this and running the queries against that is two orders of magnitude faster than what I was doing initially.

Comment: can you post an explain plan of your query

Answer (score 1):

Two things.
First create table on sql level (from pg_admin for exmaple).

```
create table polygons as
select st_geomfromtext(concat('Polygon((',x||' '||y,',',x||' 
'||y+0.2,',',x+0.4||' '||y+0.2,',',x+0.4||' '||y,',',x||' '||y,'))')) geom
  FROM (select generate_series(0,199.9,0.2) x) x,
       (select generate_series(0,199.9,0.4) y) y
```

Create index

create index on polygons using gist(geom);

Then use your query or this one. Check which one will be faster in your case

```
select id, count(*) 
  from sub_rects r 
  join gps_points g on st_dwithin(r.geom, p.geom, 0)
group by id;
```

Comment: Thank you! Your create snippet was exactly what I was looking for - I modified it to also generate an index column to refer to in the follow-up queries, but it solves the real issue quickly and beautifully. As for using st_dwithin for the matching, it did speed thing up, but only at the cost of losing a very significant portion of matches, so I will stick with maching on the bounding boxes, which should be more than adequate for rectangles and points.

Comment: It is very strange that with ST_DWithin(r.geom, p.geom,0) you loose matches. It should take every pointhat is inside of it. I think problem can be with points that are exactly on the border between two polygons as they be counted twice.
If you can show few cases that are lost in your opinion i can check why there is a difference between st_dwithin and &&

Comment: I would, but I have nowhere to upload the dataset that I run this against. Too bad, because I would love to have a second opinion on why this discrepancy occurs. I have also run something similar against a non-Postgis version with x,y as points and just numeric boundary comparison instead of Postgis rectangles, and while it's ~3 times slower, the results match the bounding box match and not at all the Dwithin one.

Comment: Oh, i read now that your gps_points data are not points but small boxes with number of points inside, so it can happen that your box for gps points with its bounding box around for index produce diffrent results then exact match cheking if gps_points box and  generated polygons are in ST_dwitihin(geom, geom, 0).
In fact both boudningboxes can overlap each other without overlaping real geoms.

To have most accurate results you should, if possible, compare real  gps_points before aggregation to small boxes with your generated polygons.
If you cannot do that use ST_dwithin

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of generating a grid from a bounding box:

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/16374/how-to-create-a-regular-polygon-grid-in-postgis

To generate the density data, try creating a temp table with all the data first and then get the count.  In my experience the below was somewhat faster than combing all into a single query:

```
create temp table rect_points as 
select r.id as rect_id, p.id as point_id 
from sub_rects r, gps_points p
where p.geom && r.geom;

create index idx on rect_points (rect_id);

select rect_id, count(*) from rect_points group by rect_id;
```

Comment: Thank you! Very interesting link, although I think that the suggested code by Grzegorz below is enough for my purposes.To run it as a temporary table is a great suggestion that I will most certainly implement.